# Programmatically add keyboard shortcut to Mac System Preferences

Tags: keyboard, applescript, macos

If I go to System Preferences, Keyboard, Keyboard Shortcuts, then Application Shortcuts, I can define custom shortcuts to be used on a Mac.

Any way to access this functionality via Applescript?

Answer (score 17):

The shortcuts are stored in NSUserKeyEquivalents dictionaries in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist and the property lists of applications.

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add Duplicate '~@d' Minimize '\0'
defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Show Package Contents"="@\r";}'
```

The shortcut format is described in the [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) article.

Answer (score 4):

System Preferences isn't scriptable with Applescript natively, you have to interact with it by [GUI Scripting](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html). GUI Scripting is really a last resort that allows you to interact with controls by explicitly declaring and calling them, and it doesn't take much to throw off a GUI script. It is difficult to implement even for experienced Applescript programmers. You'll find a few [introductory tutorials](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.06/UserInterfaceScripting/index.html) out there in the web, but not much else.

Comment: System Preferences does have a basic dictionary, but you can't modify individual preferences without System Events. Many preferences (like Application Shortcuts) can be edited in property lists though.

Comment: @Lri: True, but as you point out "...you can't modify individual preferences without System Events." Thus making it such that Apple shouldn't even have bothered.

Answer (score 4):

The internals of the Mac OS are quickly becoming a lost art. Run the following in a shell, or run via shell in Applescript:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents '{ "Search the Web…" = "@k"; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written an AppleScript library to programmatically add Global & Application shortcuts. It took a tremendous amount of effort to work around the various quirks in how macOS implements shortcuts.

Version 1.0 is available here:
https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/setting-other-applications-keyboard-shortcuts-using-nsuserdefaults-defaults-not-updating/3537/5

I will be making some minor API additions & changes when I find the time, and will post the source code here in full at that time. Note that as mentioned above, Services shortcuts are stored using a completely different system & are not handled here.

Answer (score 0):

Also good to know: shortcuts for **Services** are in the **pbs.plist**, and they're stored using a different property than the NSUserKeyEquivalents.

There's info on how to write a basic script to change/add shortcuts for Services here:

[Set Services keyboard shortcut via script OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115675/set-services-keyboard-shortcut-via-script-osx)

This was the method I found the simplest, and it worked well for me (macOS 10.12.6 Sierra):

> You can also use PlistBuddy and defaults:
>
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete NSServicesStatus:"(null) - test2 -
> runWorkflowAsService"' ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist
> 2>/dev/null;defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '"(null) -
> test2 - runWorkflowAsService"' '{key_equivalent = "^~@2";}'
>
> The PlistBuddy command is not needed if there is not an existing entry
> for the service. Replace test2 with the name of the service. Quit and
> reopen applications to apply the changes.
>
> ^~@2 is control-option-command-2. See
> http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html.

And in case this might help those who are a bit less familiar with writing/executing scripts on macOS, I saved the script as a shell script (.sh extension), and ran it from Terminal using the following commannd:

```
sh "/path/to/script/scriptfile.sh"
```