# Creating a Mac OS keyboard shortcut from Terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

Is it possible to create a Mac OS keyboard shortcut for a menu item of a selected application from the Terminal without using AppleScript?

**The solution is described here:** [Programmatically add keyboard shortcut to Mac System Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219134/programmatically-add-keyboard-shortcut-to-mac-system-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

You could write it in AppleScript and then execute it in osascript using the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found a better solution and added it to my question.