# How to access keyboard shortcuts programmatically

Tags: ios, keyboard-shortcuts

In "Settings" -> "General" -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts",we are able to query,add and delete our shortcuts, so when we are typing a shortcut,the full phrase will be showing in the keyboard. So I am wondering if we could access the keyboard shortcuts in code.(for example,I want to add some useful phrases in my app.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: will please give an example how you want to use it ? i mean you want to use it during coding ? or during when user type something in your application ?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219134/programmatically-add-keyboard-shortcut-to-mac-system-preferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to modify the system shortcuts or access them other than the system default (i.e. when the user is typing in a text field or similar).

However, you can check what the user types in a text field within your application using the corresponding `delegate` methods (e.g. in `UITextFieldDelegate`). When you detect a shortcut you would like to replace, you get the text field's text and replace the shortcut with the full text.

For anything more specific, you will have to try something yourself and ask more specific questions.