# How to find a Mac terminal command to turn off a default keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to find the equivalent [terminal command](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/edit-property-lists-apda49a1bb2-577e-4721-8f25-ffc0836f6997/mac) for Mac, used to turn off these specific keyboard settings(and the checkbox at the bottom):

[image: Mac system keyboard shortcuts to turn off previous input source]

It's the control + space hotkey combination, that is also used by vscode to trigger suggestions

How can one find the correct command for turning this setting off? I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219134/programmatically-add-keyboard-shortcut-to-mac-system-preferences), but it mentions keyboard shortcuts for apps, not the system shortcuts

Comment: The setting is in the result of command [`defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys`] key `60` atribute `enabled` = 1. You need to set it to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comment of [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe):

> The setting is in the result of command [defaults read
> com.apple.symbolichotkeys] key 60 atribute enabled = 1. You need to
> set it to 0.

I managed to find the following command that sets this to disabled:

```
plutil -replace AppleSymbolicHotKeys.60.enabled -bool NO ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
```

And then using this command(or restarting the machine), we can make sure it's applied

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```

Thanks for all the help.